# How to use `$or` in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to MongoDB and I have met an issue when I use `$or` operator.

Here is my code:

```
for element in table1.find():
        total += 1
        result = table2.find_one({'guanZhi' : element['guanZhi'], 
                                  'name'    : element['name'],
                                  'minZu'   : element['minZu'],
                                  'keJu'    : element['keJu']})

        if result and (element['qiFen'] == result['qiFen'] or 
                       element['qiFen'] == result['qiFenHuo']):
            pass
        else:
            failed += 1
```

About `(element['qiFen'] == result['qiFen'] or element['qiFen'] == result['qiFenHuo'])`, I want use `$or`, but I don't know how to write the code.

I changed it like this:

```
for element in table1.find({'ji': ""}):
        if table2.find_one({'guanZhi' : element['guanZhi'],
                            'name'    : element['name'],
                            'minZu'   : element['minZu'],
                            'nian'    : element['nian'],
                            '$or'     : [{'qiFen' : element['qiFen']}, {'qiFenHuo': element['qiFen']}]}):
            match.write(formatElement(element))
        else:
            no_match.write(formatElement(element))
            failed += 1
```

but I am confused with it, does this code look alright?
i want:

```
(guanZhi' : element['guanZhi']) and 
('name' : element['name'])      and 
('minZu'   : element['minZu'])  and 
('keJu': element['keJu'])       and 
({'qiFen' : element['qiFen']}   or  {'qiFenHuo': element['qiFen']})
```

Comment: sorry, why tag `javascript` is here?

Comment: That looks alright! Did you face any issue in execution?

Comment: I have update my question

Comment: @BlackMamba even the updated one looks fine!

Comment: you mean  `'$or'     : [{'qiFen' : element['qiFen']}, {'qiFenHuo': element['qiFen']}]` is right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think you need to include both an $AND operator and an $OR operator...

What I understand you're trying to get is:
"the document you've specified" 
    AND ({'qiFen' : element['qiFen']} 
         OR 'qiFenHuo': element['qiFen']})

If so... try combining your code with something like this:

```
db.inventory.find( {
    $and : [
        // YOUR CODE HERE,
        { $or : [ { sale : true }, { qty : { $lt : 20 } } ] }
    ]
} )
```

Comment: It looks fine as long as it does what you want it to do. Meaning, that even if you don't get exceptions, you need to make sure the logic is what you want (otherwise, that'll be a bug). Right now, you're telling Mongo to find the first document that fulfills one of two options.. The two options are similar, where only one field is different. But still, even if both versions exist, you'll only.get the first one Mongo finds. And of course, you have to write it in Mongo syntax.